# using django permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly with token authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

I have this Django API view that I want to allow authorized and unauthorized users access it, I have set Django token-authentication as the default authentication class, however, whenever I try to access the view as unauthenticated user,I get error **Unauthorized:** which is weird coz am making a get request in the view
my code is here

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def all_Search(request):
    print(request.headers)
    src = request.GET.get('q')
```

my settings for rest framework is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

is there a way to work around this? will appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your error but I failed.
This is my configuration:

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', api.all_search, name="search")

]
```

`api.py`

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def all_Search(request):
    print(request.headers)
    src = request.GET.get('q')
    return Response()
```

`test.py`

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APILiveServerTestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

class TestTokenAuthorization(APILiveServerTestCase):
    def test_can_search_without_token(self):
        url = reverse('search', kwargs={})
        response = self.client.get(url, {}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and this is the result of the test:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
{'Cookie': '', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I'm using `djangorestframework==3.10.3` and `python3.7`

As you can see, I didn't authenticate the request (no token is passed) and the headers were printed as expected from the permissions.

Maybe your issue is caused by something else in your code. Try to include more details in your question.

By the way, your `all_Search` function is missing the `return Response()`

Comment: I think my issue was the fact that frontend included token in the headers in every request made, so django was trying to get to authenticated a user that had the empty or null token thanks for this, you just made me realize that I should also include a check for null token in frontend and avoid passing it in the header if it is blank

Answer (score 0):

Okey I just decided to try something and it seams to be working, at least for now. I somehow believed that **DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES** was the issue in this case and in deed it was, so I had to just remove the

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

#opt to use
#authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
#in my views that requires authentications
```

in my settings, this was not all though, but now I could access the view either authorized or not: (having auth token or not). but this was not getting authenticated user by default
so I did this

make a view to get a user based on a given token

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

def get_user(token):
    try:
        token = Token.objects.select_related('user').get(key=token)
        return token.user
    except:
        return AnonymousUser
```

and get user in my view if token exists in the headers

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def all_Search(request):
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[1]
    key = request.headers.get('Authorization').split(' ')[0]
    if key == 'Token' and auth != 'null': #used null coz my frontend sends null if key is not available
        user = get_user(auth)
        print(user)
```